# Webhooks not being received

Tags: evernote

I've registered to have my consumer key activated for production and for web hooks notifications.

I have connected my app to my user account and I had received the emails but when checking my server logs after creating a note I do not receive a request to my server.

I have tried requests to the URL from other services and it works fine but Evernote's requests aren't coming through.

I understand there isn't any Evernote support is there anyone that can look in to this?

Comment: Probably okay to close or delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was that I was using a "Let's Encrypt" SSL Certificate and Evernote does not support the root CA certificate.

I switched over to a cheaper Comodo SSL Certificate and everything worked fine after a while.